# ActiveRecord querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have `Task` and `Project` tables, project has many tasks.

How to get the count of all tasks in each project, order by tasks count descending?

I came up only with `Task.group('project_id')`, not any further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `count` after `group`, like `Task.group(:project_id).count`, this will give you a hash with `project_id` as keys and numbers of their tasks as values. Then you may sort them using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: It definitely might work but it won't be a pure ActiveRecord query.

Comment: @megas Yes you are right. I also would like to know how to do this in a pure ActiveRecord query.

Comment: It's nice to ask question which is also useful for somebody else :)